# InterlockedExchange Visual Studio 2010 Intrinsic

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, atomic, intrinsics, interlocked

I have intrinsics enabled in the optimization settings for the compiler, however, the resulting code for InterlockedExchange is generating calls into kernel32.dll rather than producing inline assembly. This is especially problematic because the function is not available on versions of windows prior to Vista.

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states "*This function is implemented using a compiler intrinsic where possible*". Is it possible to get the compiler to use actual intrinsic code for InterlockedExchange?

Comment: Documentation (see your own link) says: "Minimum supported client - Windows 2000 Professional"

Comment: I'm actually using InterlockedExchange64 which is only available on Vista and above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the interlocked intrinsics require an underscore prefix (or `#pragma intrinsic`), so you want to use [`_InterlockedExchange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/1s26w950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you will also need to include `intrin.h`

also, you you read your quote fully, it says this:

> This function is implemented using a compiler intrinsic where
>   possible. For more information, see the Winbase.h header file and
>   **_InterlockedExchange**.